# How to mark up food product's nutritional information with Schema.org?

Tags: product, schema.org

I'm looking for a way to mark up food **product**'s **nutritional information** with Schema.org (JSON-LD, Microdata, or RDFa). My attempts so far won't validate in [Google's Structured data testing tool](https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool).

By "food product" I mean something like a **box of cereal** *or* a **carton of orange juice**.

Unfortunately, according to this page http://schema.org/nutrition,
nutritional information markup is only explicitly supported on [`MenuItem`](http://schema.org/MenuItem) and [`Recipe`](http://schema.org/Recipe) types. Neither of these 2 options *feel* correct to me in this case. Perhaps an argument could be made for [`MenuItem`](http://schema.org/MenuItem).

I haven't yet come across an example site that marks up food products' nutrition, so I'm not sure if there is a solution currently [13th June 2017].

---

#### A reduced JSON-LD example of an attempt that results in error when tested on [Google's Structured data testing tool](https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool):

```html
<script type="application/ld+json">
  {
    "@context": "http://schema.org",
    "@type": "Product",
    "name": "Orange Juice 250ml",
    "nutrition": {
      "@type": "NutritionInformation",
      "calories": "X calories"
    }
  }
</script>
```

#### Resulting error:

> The property `nutrition` is not recognised by Google for an object of type `Product`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Schema.org doesn’t have a suitable type/property for your use case yet.

1. The [`NutritionInformation`](http://schema.org/NutritionInformation) type can only be added with the [`nutrition`](http://schema.org/nutrition) property.
2. The `nutrition` property can only be added to [`MenuItem`](http://schema.org/MenuItem) and [`Recipe`](http://schema.org/Recipe) types.

---

If you are fine with representing your food products as menu items, you could use `MenuItem` and `Product` together:

```json
"@type": ["Product", "MenuItem"],
```

Google’s SDTT doesn’t report an error as long as at least one of the specified types allows a property.

But maybe you don’t need `Product` in the first place. You can add an `Offer` to the `MenuItem` directly (with the [`offers`](http://schema.org/offers) property).

---

Schema.org might introduce a `Food` (or similarly named) type in the future. See their issue [*Create a new Food type (help further with foodWarning and recipeIngredient)*](https://github.com/schemaorg/schemaorg/issues/458).